# There's a most performant way to check that a collection has exactly 1 element?

Tags: c#, linq

I came up with this solution :

```
if (Take(2).Count() == 1)
```

is there any more performance solution (or better syntactical sugar) to do this check ?
I want a performance way because this will be an extension used on Linq To Entites and Linq to Objects.

I'm not using `SingleOrDefault` because that will throw and exception if it has more than 1 element.

Based on @Telastyn answer I came up with the following:

```
public static bool HasOne<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
    var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    return enumerator.MoveNext() && !enumerator.MoveNext();
}
```

another implementation (slighly slower but 100% sure will work effectivly on Linq to Entities) would be :

```
public static bool HasOne<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
    return !enumerable.FirstOrDefault().Equals(default(T)) && !enumerable.Skip(1).Any();
}
```

I'm not sure if the `MoveNext` one works with IQueryable on Linq to Entites. (any takers? I don't know how to test that)

After some test, `Take(2).Count() == 1`; is the fastest. :S

Comment: But why do you think that a simple .Count() is not "performant"?

Comment: Wouldn't the performance depend on the specific type of collection and its implementation?

Comment: @JK01 I didn't `know` but run some test and with 40,000 elements, with count it takes 00.0004618 while with the solution with `MoveNext` only takes 00.0000067. With 2 elemnts `3169` vs `0011` and with 1 elements it's the same. As bigger the collection, count gets slower.

Comment: And how many elements do you have? Both of those times effectively the same to a human - instant.  You are not going to get support tickets complaining about slow speed either way.

Comment: @Snowman I'm pretty sure that MoveNext() it's optimized for all collections. Any particular collection you think I should test for Count vs MoveNext ?

Comment: @JK01 it's an extension method that can (and will) be used intensively/freely on a big application so performance can be an issue when running it multiple times with lots of request per second.

Comment: @Bart never mind, you are right, I was confused.

Comment: @Bart If you are really that worried about performance, then you should not be using LINQ, but using collections directly.

Comment: @Euphoric can you provide an example?

Comment: @Bart Example of what? Using collection directly? Thats the basic of basics. It is as simple as getting Lenght on array and comparing it to 1.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what IEnumerable.Count() does?

Comment: @Bart Not really. http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/07-Count-And-LongCount.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981254/is-the-linq-count-faster-or-slower-than-list-count-or-array-length

Comment: Your second solution doesn't dispose the enumerator. Add a `using` block.

Comment: The third one is horrible: 1) It doesn't work if the sequence returns `null` elements 2) It enumerates the sequence twice

Comment: SingleOrDefault should never throw. It would just return default.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen That's not [what the documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451): "InvalidOperationException: The input sequence contains more than one element."

Comment: I stand corrected. I was 99% sure.

Comment: @JK01 This is thread necromancy here, but running count on an arbitrary IEnumerable is fairly dangerous. The enumerable could be very large. It could infinite. It could be calculating prime numbers, or digits of pi, or anything that could make calling count very expensive. It is much much safer to do what the OP suggests if you actually just want to make sure it only has 1, especially if you don't know the implementation or actual size of the the enumerable.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, making your own extension that returns false on the second successful `MoveNext` (or none) should be the most performant implementation for `IEnumerable`. Anything with a `Count` property should just check if it is equal to one.

Comment: makes lot of sense. Can you provide me a naive example ? Not familiar with yield.

Comment: @bart - sorry, my first draft included the yield comment which isn't appropriate in this case. It's just going to use `MoveNext` three times.

Comment: @bart - and `.Skip(1).Any()` I think should produce he right results and be speedy too.

Comment: .Skip(1).Any() will not work because it will return true when collection have 2+ elements and false on 1 or 0 elements.

Comment: @Bart - ah, yes, sorry, skip 1 not any.

Comment: Skip 1 not any wont work either. False on 2+ and True on 0 and 1.